# How to prevent getch() from getting input data that was entered too soon?

Tags: c++

Simple code to understand the problem:

```
string op;
int main()
{
    cout<<"hi";
    op=getch(); // or cin>>op
    delay(2000) // delay for 2 sec.
    cout<<endl<<" bye";
    op=getch(); // or cin>>op
    system("cls"); 
    cout<<"  MAGIc !! !!";
    return 0;
}
```

What this code should be doing is:

1. Print "hi"
2. Wait for the user to press any key
3. Wait for two seconds
4. Print "bye"
5. Wait for the user to press any key again
6. Clear the screen
7. Print "Magic"

Let's say there are two users: User A and User B.

Let's say User A presses the 'a' key and then waits for two seconds until "bye" is displayed, and then presses 'a' again and then sees the screen clear and "magic" get printed. Well User A is good, and there is no problem.

But let's User B is impatient. User B sees "hi" and immediately presses 'a' twice. Then after two seconds, he only sees the word "Magic". He never sees "bye" because the screen is cleared right away!

So the question is: how do I prevent the second `getch()` from getting input if an impatient user presses too many keys before "bye" is printed, so that they have to press another key *after* "bye" is printed and *before* the screen is cleared?

Comment: Call `cout.flush()`

Comment: what does it do? and how does it help ! and how to use?

Comment: It will output the written characters immediately to the output streams device.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That won't help here: the problem is that `getch()` is being used as a hack for "wait for a keypress" -- but there's already input waiting in standard input, so the program immediately continues to the command that clears the screen.

Comment: could you write a fix code?

Comment: @Hurkyl so is there way to fix my problem !?

Comment: you always need to flush buffer

Comment: If you're on windows you might be able to do something like `while (kbhit()) { getch(); }` immediately after the delay. You would need to add `#include <conio.h>`. That would clear out any characters that were inputted during the delay, then the next `op=getch();` would have to wait for another key to be pressed.

Comment: @jonhopkins tried earlier ! but not helpful! still not fixed! and just add the ur solve code with my code ! what if the user enter 'a' 3 times! Still same prolem

Comment: one question: what is the role of `system("cls")`??

Comment: @Raindrop7 to show that the bye is skipped !

Comment: It clears the screen. That's what the problem is, if there's already input waiting for the second `getch()`, then it processes immediately and the `cout << "bye"` gets cleared away before the user can see it

Comment: @jonhopkins !! thats what! How to fix it !

Comment: Other than what I mentioned earlier, best I can find is `cin.clear(); cin.ignore(INT_MAX);`, but since you're not using `cin` to get the input, I'm not sure if that would help unless you change how you're getting the characters.

Comment: @jonhopkins  ! well for cin ! the better solution would be to use getline(cin, op); // i am i correct!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for being too late. in your case use: FlushConsoleInputBuffer to clear getch buffer:

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"hi";
    op=getch();
    Delay(2000);
    cout<<endl<<" bye";

    FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)); // flushing the buffer
    op=getch(); // or cin>>op
    system("cls"); 
    cout<<"  MAGIc !! !!";
    return 0;
}
```

user above can enter even 4 times a and everything will be alright.

- it's so stupid to clear cin's buffer without using it

Comment: just waited few days to get other answer if possible! dont worry, i will mark your answer soon! "Every hard-work as a reward!!"

Comment: if it doesn't work for you than it's ok to remove it